# Оценить приложение в самом приложении

Tags: android, google-play

Возможно ли оценить приложение по нажатию на кнопку(к примеру), при этом не переходя на страницу Google Play?

Возможно ли как-то проверять оценил пользователь приложение или нет ?

Сейчас сделано так, что при нажатию на кнопку - пользователю открывается страница в маркете.

Comment: 1. Нет. 2. Нет.

Comment: @metalurgus, это 100%, что нельзя так сделать ? Напишите ответ, приму его.

Answer (score 6):

1. *Возможно ли оценить приложение по нажатию на кнопку(к примеру), при этом не переходя на страницу `Google Play`?*
   Нельзя. У `Google Play` нет такого API, и *никогда не будет*. Почему? - Потому, что любое приложение имело бы возможность само себе ставить оценки от имени пользователей.
2. *Возможно ли как-то проверять оценил пользователь приложение или нет?*
   Нет. Потому, что вы никак не сможете узнать, кто поставил оценку. `Google Play` опять же не предоставляет такой возможности, что по моему мнению *правильно* (анонимная оценка)

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тому что ни в одном из многих десятков приложений с которыми мне приходилось сталкиватся, не реализованно такое, а всегда есть предложение оценить в магазине - то можно оценить только в магазине.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле проверить оставил ли пользователь комментарий в google play-e можно, но не традиционным способом =). Вот [этот](http://apptools.ru/) сервис тому доказательство. По крайней мере раньше после установки приложения он требовал оставить оценку. Несколько лет назад я делал похожий продукт и у заказчика было такое же требование. В итоге придумал такое решение:

```
public static void getCommentsFromMarket(final int pageNumber, final String uid, String marketName, final CallBack callBack) {
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        String url = "https://play.google.com/store/getreviews";
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

        try {
            client.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0");
            client.addHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            client.addHeader("Accept-Language", "ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
            client.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            client.addHeader("Accept-Charset", "windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
            client.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
            client.addHeader("Referer", "https://play.google.com");
            params.put("reviewType", "0");
            params.put("pageNum", String.valueOf(pageNumber));
            params.put("id", marketName);
            params.put("reviewSortOrder", "0");
            params.put("xhr", "1");
            params.put("hl", "ru");

            client.post(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String result) {

                    //  postDataToServer(pageNumber, uid, result, new CallBack());

                    if (result.contains(uid)) {
                        callBack.onSuccess(true);
                    } else {
                        callBack.onSuccess(false);
                    }
                }

                public void onFailure(Throwable th) {

                    callBack.onFail(th.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            callBack.onFail(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
```

где `int pageNumber` - номер страницы с комментариями,
`String uid` - id пользователя в google plus. В примере использовал библиотеку [asyncHttpClient](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). Собственно метод приходилось прогонять циклом по 10-ти страницам, т.к. как правило свежий коммент находился всегда в их рамках.

Comment: Хм.. очень интересно. Надо разобраться! Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: =) Всегда пожалуйста

Comment: жаль, что это может работать только для оценок с комментариями... Как вариант, можно требовать от пользователя оставить комментарий с определенным текстом (случайно сгенерированным кодом)

Comment: @metalurgus Если честно, то без комментария не проверял, может и работает=) А так, полностью согласен